# struggle simplifying $\sqrt{9+\sqrt{5}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

I need to simplify $\sqrt{9+\sqrt{5}}$

I already do this (proven it) $\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{5}}=2-
\sqrt{5}$

But I couldn't when apply to $\sqrt{9+\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{9-4\sqrt{5}+5\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{5})^2+5\sqrt{5}}$

PLEASE help me out

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \neq x+y$.

Comment: The expression is as simple as it gets. Why would you expect it simplifies more?

Comment: so that i prove that $\sqrt{9+\sqrt{5}}*(2-\sqrt{5})=1$

Comment: This is not true. The actual identity is $\sqrt{9+4\sqrt5}\cdot(2-\sqrt5)=1$.

Comment: okey thanks andres i know how to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose
$\sqrt{9+\sqrt{5}}
= a+\sqrt{b}
$.

Squaring both sides,
$9+\sqrt{5}
= a^2+b+2a\sqrt{b}
= a^2+b+\sqrt{4a^2b}
$.

Equating the parts,
$9 = a^2+b$
and
$5 = 4a^2b$.

From the second,
$a^2 = 5/(4b)$,
so, from the first,
$9 = 5/(4b)+b$,
or $4b^2-36b+5 = 0$.

The discriminant is
$d = 36^2-4\cdot 4\cdot 5
=16(9^2-5)
=16\cdot 76
=64\cdot 39
$.
This is not a square of an integer,
so there is no integer (or rational)
expression in a simplified form.

You could, of course,
write
$\sqrt{9+\sqrt{5}}
= 3\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}/9}
$,
but this doesn't seem 
to be worth much.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt{9+\sqrt{5}}=A+B \sqrt{5}$. Square each side: $9+\sqrt{5} = A^2 + 2AB \sqrt{5} + 5 B^2$. Now we get two equations and two unknowns and solve for $A$ and $B$...

Comment: i don't know how to solve for a and b

Comment: @user113224: $$A^2+5B^2=9\;\;,\;\;2AB=1$$

Comment: In general, this is how you approach the problem. In this case, it turns out that there are no integer or rational solutions, so your original equation is as good as it gets.